# What is the executor property for the MEMBER_ROLE_UPDATE audit log if the role is managed by an integration?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm creating a Discord logging bot to log all the role updates to the members of my server and also who executed those changes. I've observed some of the audit log entries for the audit log action `MEMBER_ROLE_UPDATE` and I get this:

```js
GuildAuditLogsEntry {
  targetType: 'USER',
  actionType: 'UPDATE',        
  action: 'MEMBER_ROLE_UPDATE',
  reason: null,
  executor: User {
    id: '334911278298562561',  
    bot: false,
    username: 'Pritt',
    discriminator: '0780',
    avatar: 'e5e205996571c0c7c4e69246027fb1f8',
    flags: UserFlags { bitfield: 256 },
    lastMessageID: null,
    lastMessageChannelID: null
  },
  changes: [ { key: '$add', old: undefined, new: [Array] } ],
  id: '732185365166817280',
  extra: null,
  target: User {
    id: 'hidden',
    bot: false,
    username: 'hidden',
    discriminator: '3203',
    avatar: 'hidden',
    flags: UserFlags { bitfield: 256 },
    lastMessageID: null,
    lastMessageChannelID: null
  }
}
```

This is fairy simple, its a log I collected for when I updated the role of a user in my server. I can see the `executor` property is the user object.

My only confusion is when the role in question is managed by an integration (such as the nitro booster role or any of the bot roles). These roles cannot be manually assigned or removed by any members so the executor of the audit log entry cannot be a user. What would this property be then?

Comment: I tested adding a bot to a guild with some permissions, creating a managed role. There was no audit log entry from Discord about the role update, but there was a `BOT_ADD` one. I'm not sure what will happen for a nitro booster role — maybe there will also be no log.

Comment: The documentation for Discord.js does not mention that the [.executor](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildAuditLogsEntry?scrollTo=executor) property can be optional, only that it is always a `User`, which could support @cherryblossom's findings

Comment: Also, [Discord's API docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/audit-log#audit-log-entry-object) says that `user_id` is non-nullable, which is [what Discord.js uses](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/master/src/structures/GuildAuditLogs.js#L323-L325) for `executor`.